# grid layout with resize horizontal not resizing columns

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid, grid-layout

I've got a grid layout and I'm using `resize: horizontal` on one. It lets me resize the box but it doesn't resize the other columns as I would expect it to.

```css
html,
body,
.main {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(100px, 200px) 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr;
  gap: 2px 2px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas: "header-box header-box" "left-box main-box";
}

.header-box {
  background-color: lightblue;
  grid-area: header-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left-box {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  grid-area: left-box;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
}

.main-box {
  background-color: lightpink;
  grid-area: main-box;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="header-box">header box</div>
  <div class="left-box">left box</div>
  <div class="main-box">main box</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to do like I show you in my previous answer. `auto 1fr` and you set an intial width

Comment: and  `minmax(100px, 200px)` is simply equal to 200px so this is your initial width

Comment: I want to make it so the column can go between 100px to 200px.

Comment: add a max-width and a min-width to the column

Comment: @TemaniAfif I get it now. At first I didn't understand how the other post applied to this one but now I get it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`minmax(100px, 200px)` is as good as `200px` if you want shrinking behavior change to `minmax(100px, 1fr)`

If you want the grid to responsed to the content rather than the available width of it's own parent change to `display: inline-grid;`

```css
html,
body,
.main {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.main {
  display:inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(100px, 1fr) 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr;
  gap: 2px 2px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas: "header-box header-box" "left-box main-box";
}

.header-box {
  background-color: lightblue;
  grid-area: header-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left-box {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  grid-area: left-box;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
}

.main-box {
  background-color: lightpink;
  grid-area: main-box;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="header-box">header box</div>
  <div class="left-box">left box</div>
  <div class="main-box">main box</div>
</div>
```